# YOLO and adjusting number of anchor boxes for custom dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection, conv-neural-network, yolo

I am working on implementing YOLO v2 and 3 for object detection on a custom dataset. While YOLO v2 and 3 use something like 5 or so anchor boxes, I generally have maybe 50-100 detections each image. My sense is that if there are only 5 anchor boxes, then there are at most 5 detections per image right? So I was trying to understand if I needed to adjust the number of anchor boxes to my dataset.

**My questions is, does the number of anchor boxes need to be larger than the maximum count of bounding boxes in any training image?** That way, I would never run into detections where there is no corresponding anchor box. Is that the right way of thinking about adapting YOLO?

If my intuition is correct then would I need to do k-means to cluster the bounding boxes in the ground truth images and set the anchor box coordinates. Then I would use the usual regression method as specified in this [blog post](http://christopher5106.github.io/object/detectors/2017/08/10/bounding-box-object-detectors-understanding-yolo.html).

Thanks for any help that anyone can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My sense is that if there are only 5 anchor boxes, then there are at most 5 detections per image right?

There are five anchor boxes for each prediction cell and not for the whole image. Lets consider Yolo v2, where the input image is of size `416x416x3` and outputs is `13x13xN` . Each of the 13x13 corresponds to a 32x32 cell region in the input image (as shown in the image below from the blog post) and for each of the 13x13 cells there are 5 anchors defined. So you can technically have 13x13x5 bounding boxes for an image of size 416x416 (You can train with larger images as well, as yolo v2 is a fully convolutional network and then you get more cell regions). 
[image]

Lets say you have 50 bounding boxes in your image, each of the bounding box should be assigned to a cell based on how close the center of the bounding box is to the cell center. Now for this cell pick one of the 5 anchor boxes which gives the best IOU. For each cell construct a label that should contain confidence scores and box position and dimension of all 5 anchor boxes (except for the anchor box selected, others will be marked zero) along with the class scores.

On the k-means clustering mentioned in the link, it describes how they arrived at the five anchor boxes. Its better you just stick with the 5 bounding boxes, unless you have any specific reasons to include more or have different shapes if any specific requirement arises.

Comment: Okay this makes sense. So each of the 13 x 13 reduced pixels is defined with 5 anchor boxes. Then the CNN will determine whether the specified objects actually are centered in that pixel. This makes sense. In the blog post it talks about how the final bounding box dimensions are computed by regression. So using the 32x32 receptive field the YOLO algorithm computes the dimensions of the predicted bounding box--even if that bounding box is larger than the 32x32 receptive field.

Comment: The cnn will predict for that pixel where is the center, it need not be in the center of the cell, if you see how the box dimensions are encoded in the blog, there is `(bx ,by)`,which gives how far is it from the center `(cx, cy)`.

Comment: Yep, I get it now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The number of anchor boxes *partilly* affects the number of detected boxes.

The output of YOLOv2 has shape (13, 13, B*(5+C)), where **B is the number of anchor boxes** and C is the number of classes you're trying to detect. Thus the output has 13*13=169 **grid cells**. You can think of them as a division of the input image into 13 by 13 cells.

Each grid cell can detect *at most* B objects or bonding boxes. The number of bonding boxes that a grid cell detects depends on its **confidence** values. Each B bounding boxes of a grid cell has a confidence, which is between 0 and 1. If the confidence of a box is greater than a **threshold**, the network finally tells us that a box (or object) is *detected*.

Let's say that a grid cell has the following confidence values, and the threshold is 0.1.

[0.02, 0.3, 0.001, 0.9, 0.03] (B=5)

In this case, this grid cell detects 2 boxes, and discards other 3 boxes with small confidence.

So if you want to decrease the number of detected boxes, **I recommend you to increase the threshold**.

[image: The output of the network looks like this. There are 13x13 = 169 grid cells in total, and each grid cell can detect up to B bounding boxes. One bounding box has 5 + C properties, therefore a grid cell has D = Bx(5+C) values (this is depth).]

Comment: Oh thanks @Yoshio. Yeah, I get what you are saying. Basically the model will detect too many boxes and then apply the threshold to prune the number of boxes according to the threshold. Thanks for reinforcing that point.